# Getting distinct call log numbers from android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am working on android project and I am trying to get the numbers from the Android call log and display them in a list view.

This is working fine except for one thing, at the moment if a number has called multiple times then it is displayed multiple times within my ListView, I only want to show distinct numbers but I can't find out how this is done.

Below is the code I am using to get the numbers

```
String[] callLogFields = {android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME};

        String viaOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
        String where = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " > 0";

        Cursor callLogCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
                callLogFields, where, null, viaOrder);

        ArrayList<Spanned> arrayList = new ArrayList<Spanned>();

        if (callLogCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String telephoneNumber = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                String date = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                Spanned content = Html.fromHtml(telephoneNumber + "<br /><small><font color='#9f9f9f'>" + date + "</font></small>");
                arrayList.add(content);
            }while (callLogCursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you want to display the number once even if the date of calling is different? If the date is same then you can just remove the duplicate entries from `ArrayList` as it contains only date and phone number.

Comment: No i'm not that bothered by the date, it should only have the number once regardless of the date.

Comment: A bad way to do this is to keep adding phone number to a different `ArrayList` and have a if condition inside your `do while` loop such that: if ( phone number not present in arraylist){ .. proceed .. }

Comment: @ShobhitPuri That is actually what I've done as a temporary measure until I can work out how to do it the prober way